# How to analyse LINQ queries

Tags: asp.net, linq

I swear I've seen how to do this before, but now that I actually need to do it I can't remember where I saw it at. I need two different things --

1) to see the actual SQL query that is generated by a LINQ query and
2) **when** the SQL query actually hits the database to do whatever (CRUD operations)

Is there a tool that will allow me to do this?

**EDIT**:

Sorry, should have given more detail.
-- LINQ to Entities is what I'm using.
-- Also, I don't have admin rights on our instance of SQL Server, so I can't use SQL Profiler. I could always call the DBA and have them do it for me, but it's a hassle. I should have mentioned that and I apologize. What I really want is a tool that I can use on my own box that will allow me to see when a LINQ query hits the database **while I am in debug mode** (debugging and stepping through the code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). It's great for seeing what LINQ to SQL is generating.

> SQL Profiler is a graphical tool that allows system administrators to monitor events in an instance of Microsoft® SQL Server™. You can capture and save data about each event to a file or SQL Server table to analyze later. For example, you can monitor a production environment to see which stored procedures are hampering performance by executing too slowly.

[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is also a great tool for writing linq and sql statements for testing.

> LINQPad compiles your queries using .NET's CSharpCodeProvider (or VBCodeProvider). Because C# and VB are statically typed, any database objects that you reference need the backing of a typed DataContext. For performance, LINQPad builds typed DataContexts on the fly using Reflection.Emit rather than generating and compiling source code. It uses LINQ to SQL rather than Entity Framework because LINQ to SQL is an order of magnitude faster in building the metamodel when instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately, I can't use SQL Profiler because I don't have rights to run it on our SQL Server instances. I'll have to mess with LINQPad to see if it gets me what I need, but really what I wanted was to see the SQL queries that were being generated by VS itself while I'm in debug mode. Sorry, should have been more explanative in my original question.

Comment: @Jagd I hate gestapo DBA's and SysAdmins that think Developers shouldn't have access to this type of information.

Comment: Yep, it drives me nuts too. I could put the database on my local instance of SQL Server and then run SQL Profiler locally, but I didn't want to do that unless it was my only option. Either way I think your answer is the most correct one even if it doesn't fit my exact scenario.

Answer (score 3):

The `.ToString()` on the `IQueryable` for *LINQ to SQL* will show you the query.

```
var myquery = from x in dbcontext.MyTable
              where x.Prop1 == someValue
              select new {
                  value1 = x.prop1,
                  value2 = 5,
              };

var sqlstring = myquery.ToString(); //<= look in this string
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few tools that can help.

L2SProf (Linq2Sql Profiler) is a for pay tool that can do a lot to help you see and optomize your queries.  http://l2sprof.com/

LinqPad is a great tool for write linq to sql queries and seeing the sql that comes out. It also lets you write c# code just to experiment with things. It's a great coding scratch pad. There is a free version, but you get extra features if you pay. http://www.linqpad.net/

Otherwise, there are instructions here for viewing the generated sql for free with builtin stuff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio 2010, turn on [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) and you'll see every request for LINQ To SQL, LINQ To Entities and generally everything that ultimately uses ADO.NET.

Comment: this looks promising. I'll take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Would likely have been a good option, but apparently IntelliTrace only comes with the Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property? (I'm assuming you're using LINQ to SQL.)

You could create a `TextWriter` which dumped a stack trace and timestamp every time it was written to, which would give you the timing information.

Comment: No, I'm using L2E, and I should have said so but I forgot. Sorry about that. Still, I'm not familiar with the DataContext.Log so I'll take a peek at it and see what I come up with. Thanks!

Comment: @Jagd: Ah. I'm afraid I don't know the equivalent for L2E.

Answer (score 0):

1. depends entirely on the ORM. Most ORMs offer some sort of `Log` property you can plug a `TextWriter` or so into. Consult the docs for ORM to learn more.
2. In general: when you use some sort of `SaveChanges` method. This ties in with (1), the logger will provide you with the information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, it is very complex: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx